# Measuring time spent in certain types of files in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

Is there a way to measure how much time I spend in certain types of files while working in vim? I would like to measure how much time I spend writing application code as opposed to tests (they all have a predefined file name *_spec.rb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [BufTimer plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/BufTimer). It times the duration in each file, so it does not exactly group by some filter, but it should be good enough.

Comment: This is excellent! Could you give me a pointer on how I could maybe save the report to a file this way I could dump the info into a file and then run my reports over time?

Comment: Open a PullRequest for saving the timings and I will implement it.